# Javascript Update Total Sum from Fields

Tags: javascript, forms

I have created the code  using Javascript but I'm getting and error when I hit the calculate button.

the formula im using is this:

`A + B + C + D x E% + F =`

The error I'm receiving is:

> {"error": "Please use POST request"}

The code im using is:

```
// define a function to perform our calculation.
function calculate() {
// retrieve the values from the amount and percentage fields
// and store them in variables.
var A = $('#A').val();
var B = $('#B').val();
var C = $('#C').val();
var D = $('#D').val();
var E = $('#E').val();
var F = $('#F').val();

// calculation
var total = A + B + C + D * (E / 100) + F;

$('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));

return false;
}

$('#calculator').submit(calculate);



<form id="calculator">
<p>Base:
    <input id="A" value="0.00" />
</p>
<p>Rush:
    <input id="B" value="0.00" />
</p>
<p>Added:
    <input id="C" value="0.00" />
</p>
<p>Extra:
    <input id="D" value="0.00" />
</p>
<p>Ship:
    <input type ="hidden" id="E" value="5" />
</p>
<p>
    <input id="F" value="0.00" />
</p>
<hr />
<p>Total:
    <input id="total" disabled="disabled" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: I've create a plugin to make such task easier, try this http://www.xsanisty.com/calx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have create a plugin to create calculation form called calx, you can download it [here](https://github.com/ikhsan017/calx) 
just define data formula in the target element, and initialize calx

```
<form id="calculator">
    <p>Base: <input type="text" id="A" value="0.00" /></p>
    <p>Rush: <input type="text" id="B" value="0.00" /></p>
    <p>Added: <input type="text" id="C" value="0.00" /></p>
    <p>Extra: <input type="text" id="D" value="0.00" /></p>
    <p>Ship: <input type ="hidden" id="E" value="5" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="F" value="0.00" /></p>
    <hr />
    <p>Total: <input type="text" id="total" disabled="disabled" data-formula="$A + $B + $C + $D * ($E/100) + $F" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" id="calculate" /></p>
</form>
```

javascript section

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#calculator').calx({autocalculate:false});
    $('#calculate').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#calculator').calx('update');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an unhandled `TypeError` from the middle of `calculate()`:

```
$('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
// TypeError: Object 0.000.000.0000.00 has no method 'toFixed'
```

With it being thrown, `return false;` isn't evaluated and the `<form>` still submits as normal. And, `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` is JSFiddle's way of refusing to handle the request since it's sent with `HTTP GET`.

The error is because `total`, `A`, `B`, etc. aren't `Number`s and [`+` also concatenates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators):

```
var total = A + B + C + D * (E / 100) + F;
// total = "0.00" + "0.00" + ... + "0.00";
```

`<input>` values are always `String`s, so you'll need to [parse them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) in order to *add* `Number`s rather than *concat* `String`s:

```
var A = parseFloat($('#A').val());
var B = parseFloat($('#B').val());
var C = parseFloat($('#C').val());
var D = parseFloat($('#D').val());
var E = parseFloat($('#E').val());
var F = parseFloat($('#F').val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wKr3u/

---

And, while the differences are negligible in most cases, [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) (as [Jeff Mercado suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386350/15031)) has one benefit over `return false`:

It can be used sooner in the event handler, allowing the default action to still be prevented despite an error.

```
function calculate(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    // retrieve the values from the amount and percentage fields
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Good point about the advantage of `preventDefault()` in making the handler more fault tolerant. Guess I was a bit hasty in criticizing that other answer. :/

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you want it to just calculate the total without actually submitting, you need to stop the submit event from proceeding:

```
$('#calculator').on('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    calculate();
});
```

Comment: -1 Superfluous change. The `return false` should be handling this.

Answer (score 0):

On your code `total.toFixed(2)` giving this error and by default javascript will take the value as string so You have to handle that to

**Update**

string to number just do like this

`var total = A*1 + B*1 + C*1 + D * (E / 100) + F*1;`

[HERE IS THE SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/sfh7v/3/)

Comment: Well, you sort of identified the problem (need to coerce strings to numbers), but you should have given the solution in your post, not *only* in a fiddle.